# iOS NSArray, NSSet versus Core Data Query (Fetch Request)

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray, nsset

My boss and I are trying to figure out what is the best way to handle data from core data and we are trying to figure out the pros and cons for two different ways of handling it. We are looking at the efficiency of the different methods.

1) We store each table in the data model into an NSArray or NSSet and only make fetch requests when a row has been modified or has a row added to it. We then manipulate the NSArray and NSSets to what we need by filtering them with predicates.

2) We set up the fetch request in the beginning to grab only the data that we need with compound predicates, and then go from there.

We tested the timing between the two. Option 1) 0.000259 seconds
                                      Option 2) 0.000528 seconds

We have a couple things we are thinking about as well. Option 1 seems to be faster however is that only because we are handling only about a couple hundred rows of data AND will we run into a memory issue if the arrays get way to big say we start hitting a million rows.

We think option 2 should have been the faster one, but again is it slower just because there isn't enough data? AND will it run into a memory problem if there is a million rows?

If you can explain why one will be more efficient than the other that will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to pull a million objects into memory and then filter them there. That is vastly inefficient. Databases have been optimized to be very good at filtering large data sets. You should let SQLite do the heavy lifting instead of pushing all objects through the whole Core Data stack.

If possible you mostly should go through relationships to get to your data.

If you need to use a fetch request (e.g. because you want to query all data or you want to search for specific objects) then you should make your predicate as narrow as possible and only pull the objects into the context which you really need.

In order to make a fetch request fast, you should order the predicates from cheap to expensive (see Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-CJBDBHCB)) and use appropriate indexes on the entity. We wrote some things about this in [objc.io issue #4](http://www.objc.io/issue-4), specifically [Fetch Requests](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-fetch-requests.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with large(r) datasets and `NSArray's`.  So far the largest dataset I have worked with in an array is roughly 8200 rows.  I have found great performance with something that size.  An array of 1/2 million might well pose a memory issue.

The reason that #2 is slower is that hitting managed objects and the `Core Data` stack is more overhead than simply dealing with an array.

My advice is to build a testing app that you can use to populate a large array and see what kind of performance you get and what the memory issues might be.  Using Instruments for this will help you understand better which scenario is likely to be best in even extreme cases.

Comment: In #1, what if the the entity has quite large numbers of properties?  And some properties might contain large amount of data?